# Taylor series for multivariable functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, tensor-products

To expend the function of multiple variables
$$
f({\bf x})=f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n):\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R
$$
in Taylor series around $\bf 0$, we have
$$
f({\bf x})=f({\bf 0})+Df({\bf 0})\cdot{\bf x}+\frac{1}{2}{\bf x}^{\mathrm T}\cdot DDf({\bf 0})\cdot{\bf x}+\dots
$$

My question:

> How about the third order term? Is there a better way to write down the third (and higher) order terms?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "better way"? The third term is a rank-three tensor $\nabla^3f$ multiplied by three copies of $x$. Probably the most compact way of writing it down is using Einstein summation notation
$$\frac{1}{6}\nabla^3 f_{ijk} x_ix_jx_k$$
though I've considered (mostly tongue in cheek) notation like
$$\frac{1}{6}\begin{array}{c}  x \\ \vert  \\  \nabla^3 f\\  /\qquad \backslash \\ x\qquad\quad\ x\end{array}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since $\nabla f$ is a $1\times n$ matrix, and $\nabla^2 f$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, is $\nabla^3 f$ a $n\times n\times n$ matrix? Moreover, I would like to ask if it is a well developed subject (since I need to operate with multiplication and derivative)?

Comment: It's an $n\times n\times n$ tensor; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor

Answer (score 1):

[Identifying $D^n f(0)$ with a multilinear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Higher_derivatives) you can write
$$\frac1{n!}D^n f(0)(x,\cdots,x)$$